# Intersections of straight lines are mirrored and shifted at an angle

Tags: javascript, math, p5.js

for an easy visualization of intersections between lines I try to write a program in p5.js
My temporary prototype has an error in the calculation of the intersection points (createIntersection). They are always mirrored by the angle and shifted by a certain unit. The conversion and definitoin of the arrays (like index number 112 / 210 ...) has to be done this way, because I have certain requirements at work due to historical code pieces.

The thick red lines should represent the polygon and the light blue straight lines are the auxiliary lines for dynamic generation.
Internally all even lines are infinite. To create a tidy view i have set a fixed length for now.

I think the error should be in the constructor of the LineData class. There I create the necessary variables "m" and "b". Or in the createIntersection() method.
I use the framework P5.

[image]

```js
class PointData {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    show() {
        if(this.x == undefined) return;
        stroke(255,0,255);
        strokeWeight(3);  
        point(this.x, this.y);
        strokeWeight(1); 
    }
}

class LineData {
    constructor(p1, p2, c, sw = 1){
        this.x1 = p1.x;
        this.y1 = p1.y;
        this.x2 = p2.x;
        this.y2 = p2.y;
        this.c = c;
        this.sw = sw;

        this.m = (this.y1 - this.y2) / (this.x2 - this.x1);
        this.b = this.y2-this.m*this.x2;
    };

    show() {
        if(this.x1 == undefined) return;
        stroke(this.c);
        strokeWeight(this.sw);
        line(this.x1, this.y1, this.x2, this.y2);
    }   

    createIntersection(line) {
        if     (this.m == Infinity && line.m == 0) return new PointData(this.x1, line.y1);
        else if(line.m == Infinity && this.m == 0) return new PointData(line.x1, this.y1);

        var px = (line.b - this.b) / (this.m - line.m);
        var py = line.m * px + line.b;

        if (px == Infinity || py == Infinity) return new PointData(undefined, undefined);
        return new PointData(px,py);
    }

    createParalelle(distance) {
        let xDiff = 0;
        let yDiff = 0;
        if(abs(this.x1 - this.x2) > abs(this.y1 - this.y2)) {
            yDiff = distance;
        } else {
            xDiff = distance;
        }
        return new LineData(new PointData(this.x1 + xDiff,this.y1 + yDiff), new PointData(this.x2 + xDiff,this.y2 + yDiff), color(0,70,200, 80));
    }
};

let varData   = new Array(99);
let lineData  = new Array(499);
let pointData = new Array(99);

function setup() {
    createCanvas(1600,800);
    // Konstanten
    lineData[112] = new LineData(new PointData(300, 400), new PointData(600, 400), color(255, 0, 0, 100), 3);
    lineData[111] = new LineData(new PointData(300, 430), new PointData(600, 430), color(255, 0, 0, 100), 3);
    lineData[110] = new LineData(new PointData(300, 460), new PointData(600, 460), color(255, 0, 0, 100), 3);
    lineData[210] = new LineData(new PointData(360, 460), new PointData(260, 150), color(255, 0, 0, 100), 3);
    lineData[211] = new LineData(new PointData(330, 460), new PointData(230, 150), color(255, 0, 0, 100), 3);
    lineData[212] = new LineData(new PointData(300, 460), new PointData(200, 150), color(255, 0, 0, 100), 3);
    
    lineData[1] = lineData[112].createParalelle(-10);
    lineData[2] = lineData[1].createParalelle(-20);
    lineData[3] = lineData[112].createParalelle(10);
    lineData[4] = lineData[211].createParalelle(-7.5);
    lineData[5] = lineData[211].createParalelle(7.5);
    lineData[6] = lineData[211].createParalelle(-15);
    lineData[7] = lineData[211].createParalelle(15);

    pointData[0]  = lineData[210].createIntersection(lineData[112]);
    pointData[1]  = lineData[5].createIntersection(lineData[112]);
    pointData[2]  = lineData[5].createIntersection(lineData[3]);
    pointData[3]  = lineData[3].createIntersection(lineData[4]);
    pointData[4]  = lineData[112].createIntersection(lineData[4]);
    pointData[5]  = lineData[112].createIntersection(lineData[212]);
    pointData[6]  = lineData[1].createIntersection(lineData[212]);
    pointData[7]  = lineData[1].createIntersection(lineData[6]);
    pointData[8]  = lineData[2].createIntersection(lineData[4]);
    pointData[9]  = lineData[2].createIntersection(lineData[5]);
    pointData[10] = lineData[1].createIntersection(lineData[7]);
    pointData[11] = lineData[210].createIntersection(lineData[1]);
    pointData[12] = lineData[210].createIntersection(lineData[112]);
}

// function Draw wird 30 mal die Sekunde aufgerufen
function draw() {
    background(10);
    lineData.forEach(line => {
        line.show();
    });
    pointData.forEach(point => {
        point.show();
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks for every idea!

Comment: Could you say what is wrong? Formulas for m,b, p.x, py calculations look correct at the first glance (while mx+b equation is not good for line representation in computer geometry - that's why you are mangling with Infinity). Make simple check with points (0,0), (1,1) and (1,0),(0,1) and output corresponding m,b and intersection point (should be 0.7071, 0.7071)

Comment: The pruple points should be where the intersection between the lines happens. But instead they are shifted by some angle and distance. And I don't represent the lines with y=ax+b I just use the function for the calculation of the intersection. But if there is a better way to do this I would be happy if you show me

Comment: [This way for lines defined by two points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line–line_intersection#Given_two_points_on_each_line). At first calculate denominator - zero one says that lines are parallel. What about simple example like I wrote?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the code in the `LineData` constructor function to

```
this.m = (this.y2 - this.y1) / (this.x2 - this.x1);
```

the intersections should be drawn correctly:

```js
class PointData {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    show() {
        if(this.x == undefined) return;
        stroke(255,0,255);
        strokeWeight(3);  
        point(this.x, this.y);
        strokeWeight(1); 
    }
}

class LineData {
    constructor(p1, p2, c, sw = 1){
        this.x1 = p1.x;
        this.y1 = p1.y;
        this.x2 = p2.x;
        this.y2 = p2.y;
        this.c = c;
        this.sw = sw;

        //this.m = (this.y1 - this.y2) / (this.x2 - this.x1);
        this.m = (this.y2 - this.y1) / (this.x2 - this.x1);
        this.b = this.y2-this.m*this.x2;
    };

    show() {
        if(this.x1 == undefined) return;
        stroke(this.c);
        strokeWeight(this.sw);
        line(this.x1, this.y1, this.x2, this.y2);
    }   

    createIntersection(line) {
        if     (this.m == Infinity && line.m == 0) return new PointData(this.x1, line.y1);
        else if(line.m == Infinity && this.m == 0) return new PointData(line.x1, this.y1);

        var px = (line.b - this.b) / (this.m - line.m);
        var py = line.m * px + line.b;

        if (px == Infinity || py == Infinity) return new PointData(undefined, undefined);
        return new PointData(px,py);
    }

    createParalelle(distance) {
        let xDiff = 0;
        let yDiff = 0;
        if(abs(this.x1 - this.x2) > abs(this.y1 - this.y2)) {
            yDiff = distance;
        } else {
            xDiff = distance;
        }
        return new LineData(new PointData(this.x1 + xDiff,this.y1 + yDiff), new PointData(this.x2 + xDiff,this.y2 + yDiff), color(0,70,200, 80));
    }
};

let varData   = new Array(99);
let lineData  = new Array(499);
let pointData = new Array(99);

function setup() {
    createCanvas(1600,800);
    // Konstanten
    lineData[112] = new LineData(new PointData(300, 400), new PointData(600, 400), color(255, 0, 0, 100), 3);
    lineData[111] = new LineData(new PointData(300, 430), new PointData(600, 430), color(255, 0, 0, 100), 3);
    lineData[110] = new LineData(new PointData(300, 460), new PointData(600, 460), color(255, 0, 0, 100), 3);
    lineData[210] = new LineData(new PointData(360, 460), new PointData(260, 150), color(255, 0, 0, 100), 3);
    lineData[211] = new LineData(new PointData(330, 460), new PointData(230, 150), color(255, 0, 0, 100), 3);
    lineData[212] = new LineData(new PointData(300, 460), new PointData(200, 150), color(255, 0, 0, 100), 3);
    
    lineData[1] = lineData[112].createParalelle(-10);
    lineData[2] = lineData[1].createParalelle(-20);
    lineData[3] = lineData[112].createParalelle(10);
    lineData[4] = lineData[211].createParalelle(-7.5);
    lineData[5] = lineData[211].createParalelle(7.5);
    lineData[6] = lineData[211].createParalelle(-15);
    lineData[7] = lineData[211].createParalelle(15);

    pointData[0]  = lineData[210].createIntersection(lineData[112]);
    pointData[1]  = lineData[5].createIntersection(lineData[112]);
    pointData[2]  = lineData[5].createIntersection(lineData[3]);
    pointData[3]  = lineData[3].createIntersection(lineData[4]);
    pointData[4]  = lineData[112].createIntersection(lineData[4]);
    pointData[5]  = lineData[112].createIntersection(lineData[212]);
    pointData[6]  = lineData[1].createIntersection(lineData[212]);
    pointData[7]  = lineData[1].createIntersection(lineData[6]);
    pointData[8]  = lineData[2].createIntersection(lineData[4]);
    pointData[9]  = lineData[2].createIntersection(lineData[5]);
    pointData[10] = lineData[1].createIntersection(lineData[7]);
    pointData[11] = lineData[210].createIntersection(lineData[1]);
    pointData[12] = lineData[210].createIntersection(lineData[112]);
}

// function Draw wird 30 mal die Sekunde aufgerufen
function draw() {
    background(10);
    lineData.forEach(line => {
        line.show();
    });
    pointData.forEach(point => {
        point.show();
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

It should be noted that the formula that is being used to calculate the intersection points works on *infinite* lines; that's why, for instance, the two leftmost points are drawn even though there is no visible intersection of lines.